# I want a full-screen image, but image is shared in the screen with other layouts

Tags: android

I want a full screen image as shown in this figure->[image: needed screen]

But I am getting this->
[image]

How to make the image "SWULJ PEEPAL TREE" appear full screen?
CODE:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
     
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
.....
....
}
```

layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/company_logo"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"

        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"

        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
         />
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/simpleSpinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:hint="Enter phone number"
              />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonOTP"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="        Send OTP         " />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use background property in your layout

- android:background="@drawable/company_logo"

Comment: Please post your code directly to the question, no need of adding extra URLs that can become invalid in future.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).